# Jenkins syntax error when using parameters in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins setup with a slave node each for Prod and UAT. I need to run a job such that if the user selects either of uat1 or uat2, the job runs on the UAT node. If the user selects prod, it should run the job in the Prod node. The job involves 
 1. Downloading the code for execution from git
 2. Based on whether UAT or Prod is selected, the ec2 instance should assume the appropriate role

In the below code, I've tried to run the first stage of setting parameters for the job as well as node selection on the master node. Thereafter I've used a script inside the script to provide a value to the agentLabel variable, to be used in the further steps, so that the job runs on the appropriate nde.

```
    pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Get Inputs') {
            steps {
                parameters {
                    string(
                        name: 'branch',
                        defaultValue: 'master',
                        description: 'Branch of code to be deployed'
                    )
                    choice(
                        name: 'service',
                        choices: 'calcs-service\naudits-service\nrate-alerts',
                        description: 'Service to be cleaned'
                    )
                    choice(
                        name: 'environment',
                        choices: 'uat1\nuat2\nprod',
                        description: 'Environement whose services need cleanup'
                    )
                }
                script {
                    switch("${environment}") {
                        case uat1:
                            agentLabel = 'uat'
                        case uat2:
                            agentLabel = 'uat'
                        case prod:
                            agentLabel = 'prod'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Clone cleanup_lambda_functions') {
            agent { 
                label "${agentLabel}"
            }
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: "*/${branch}"]],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:canstar-dev/devops.git']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Clean up Lambda un UAT') {
            agent { 
                label "${agentLabel}"
            }
            when {
                expression {"${agentLabel}" == 'uat'}
            }
            steps {
                 withAWS(role: 'arn:aws:iam::000000000006:role/cns-iam-role-delete-lambda-version') {
                    ansiColor('xterm') {
                        sh '''
                            set -x
                            set -eo pipefail
                            echo "Assumed Support role for:"
                            echo "${environment}"
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Clean up Lambda un Prod') {
            agent { 
                label "${agentLabel}"
            }
            when {
                expression {"${agentLabel}" == 'prod'}
            }
            steps {
                 withAWS(role: 'arn:aws:iam::0000000000005:role/cns-iam-role-delete-lambda-version') {
                    ansiColor('xterm') {
                        sh '''
                            set -x
                            set -eo pipefail
                            echo "Assumed Support role for Prod"
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

But this is failing with error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: WorkflowScript: 9: Missing required parameter:
>   "parameterDefinitions" @ line 9, column 17.
>                      parameters {
>                      ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 10: Missing required parameter: "trim" @ line 10,
>   column 21.
>                          string(
>                          ^
>
> 2 errors

I'm very new to writing jenkinsfiles, so it'd be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Parameters like that exist outside of the stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parameters` have to be declared in the scope of the pipeline and not in the scope of a single stage. ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters)).

The following should fix your syntax error:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    parameters {
                string(
                    name: 'branch',
                    defaultValue: 'master',
                    description: 'Branch of code to be deployed'
                )
                choice(
                    name: 'service',
                    choices: 'calcs-service\naudits-service\nrate-alerts',
                    description: 'Service to be cleaned'
                )
                choice(
                    name: 'environment',
                    choices: 'uat1\nuat2\nprod',
                    description: 'Environement whose services need cleanup'
                )
     } // close parameters
    stages {
        stage('Get Inputs') {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot in getting started. I managed to fix the rest of the issues myself and got the script working as required.